# Rails 4.2 update method fails only when called from before(:all) block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

### Update

I ran with the -b option in rspec to get the full traceback.  the clear method is called in

> actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb which is shown directly below

```
def reset_template_assertion
  RENDER_TEMPLATE_INSTANCE_VARIABLES.each do |instance_variable|
    instance_variable_get("@_#{instance_variable}").clear
  end
end
```

There is a setup_subscriptions method in this same file that is supposed to set these variable to a {}.  It looks like this method does not get called for the before(:all) blocks

```
def setup_subscriptions
  RENDER_TEMPLATE_INSTANCE_VARIABLES.each do |instance_variable|
    instance_variable_set("@_#{instance_variable}", Hash.new(0))
  end
  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

I am not sure if this is a bug, or I need to update some other gem.

### Original question (with updated traceback)

I am getting the following error when I run bundle exec rspec

```
>   1) user api get / index with no parameters passed  it returns the first 30 users
>      Failure/Error: user_and_token = gen_valid_user_and_api_token("foobar")
>      NoMethodError:
>        undefined method `clear' for nil:NilClass
>      # ... /gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:70:in `block in reset_template_assertion'
>      # ... /gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:69:in `each'
>      # ... /gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:69:in `reset_template_assertion'
>      # ... /gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:341:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Runner>'
>      # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:22:in `gen_valid_user_and_api_token'
>      # ./spec/requests/api/v1/user_api_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The method call that is failing is the `post` line below

./spec/support/utilities.rb:  line 22 is

```
post '/api/v1/signup', { user: { name: attrs[:name], email: attrs[:email], password: password, password_confirmation: password }}
```

---

full method in ./spec/support/utilities.rb:

```
def gen_valid_user_and_api_token(password)
  attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
  post '/api/v1/signup', { user: { name: attrs[:name], email: attrs[:email], password: password, password_confirmation: password }}
  raw_token = parse_json_body(response)['token']
  access_token = Token.get_number_field(raw_token) 
  target_user = Token.get_id_field(raw_token)
  user = User.find_by_id(target_user)
  { user: user, token: { api_access_token: "#{user.id}:#{access_token}" } } if user
end
```

When I call this method from a before block, it seems to work fine

```
before do
  @user_and_token = gen_valid_user_and_api_token("foobar")
  @user = @user_and_token[:user]
  @user_token_hash = @user_and_token[:token]
```

when I call this function from a before(:all) block, I get the above error.

```
before(:all) do
  @initial_user_count = User.count
  user_and_token = gen_valid_user_and_api_token("foobar")
  @valid_user = user_and_token[:user]
  @valid_token_hash = user_and_token[:token]
```

Before updating to rails 4.2.0 from rails 4.1.8 everything worked fine.

Below is my Gemfile:

The only changes I made moving from 4.1.8 to 4.2.0 were to change the rails gem, add the responders gem, and change the turbolinks gem from 1.1.1 -> 2.3.0 (which fixed an issue with "wrong number of agruments" for calls to redirect_to, which I am still trying to understand why.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

# gem 'rails', '~>4.1.0'
gem 'rails', '~>4.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'

## added for google maps
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'gmapsjs-rails'
##

gem 'rest_client'   

gem "puma"
gem "gcm"
gem "geocoder"

gem "figaro"

# gem "pg_search"

group :development, :test do

  #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
   gem 'guard', '= 2.7.3'
   gem 'rspec-rails', '~>2.14.0'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
   gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
   gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
   gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
   gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
   gem "teaspoon"
 #  gem "phantomjs-binaries"
 #  gem "phantomjs.rb"
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  #gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  #Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  #gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  #gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
  #gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.3.0'
# gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
  #gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: The error is coming from `./spec/support/utilities.rb:22` where `<some_object>.clear` is being called. Doesn't look like that part of the code is included here.

Comment: Sorry it was included, I added some detail

Comment: The call to `clear` does not appear in the given code.  Are you sure you included line 22 of `utilities.rb`?

Comment: Just so others are aware, this appears to be a 4.2 Rails bug per https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18285 (see very last comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... just cleaning up some questions I asked that were never answered

As Peter Alfvin mentioned in his comment, this was indeed a bug that I think will be fixed in the next rails release.  For what its worth, the was really no reason I needed the code I had on the before(:all) block.  I was able to move it into a before(:each) block and everything worked fine.